# Azure Functions Python install local resources

Tags: python, azure, pip, azure-functions, requirements.txt

I would like to deploy an azure function from Visual Studio Code. My function contains some custom packages, which are located in the root directory of the function project. Usually I am able to install those custom packages with `pip install -e /path/to/resource`. I initialized the time trigger function with azure core tools, which generated me the following files. The `submodules` folder I added manually.

This is the project structure:

```
my_azure_function
  ├─ .venv
  ├─ .vscode
  ├─ .funcignore
  ├─ function_app.py
  ├─ host.json
  ├─ local.settings.json
  ├─ requirements.txt
  └─ submodules
     └─ my-custom-libs
        └─ Source
           └─ my-custom-lib
              ├─ util
              │  ├─ __init__.py
              │  └─ util.py
              └─ setup.py
```

My `function_app.py` looks something like this:

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func

from util.util import my_custom_function

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.schedule(schedule="* 5 * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True,
              use_monitor=False) 
def my_super_duper_function(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    my_custom_function()
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')
```

To install my `util` package I created the following `requirements.txt` file:

```
-e ./submodules/my-custom-libs/Source/my-custom-lib
azure-functions
```

I am able to properly install the requirements locally by executing the function with `Azurite`. The function runs as expected locally. But when I try to deploy the function to Azure, the function is not shown as `loaded`. In other words: The function cannot be executed on Azure. When excluding `my_custom_function` from the function and removing the line `-e ./submodules/my-custom-libs/Source/my-custom-lib` of the `requirements.txt` file, I can run the function on Azure.

So I strongly assume, there might be a problem by installing my local modules.

Unfortunately there are no errors in the logs while deploying. The function simply does not show in my function-app.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

I tried to build the function locally by running the command `func azure functionapp publish my_function_app --build local`. This did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this below code for custom pacakge with python.

```py
app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.schedule(schedule="*/5 * * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True, use_monitor=False)
def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    request_data = '{"module": "numpy"}'  # Replace with your actual request data
    response = call_package_installer(request_data)
    
    logging.info(response)
```

- Code to install some custom packages from the `submodules` folder

```py
def  main(req_data):

try:

req_body = json.loads(req_data)

if  'module'  in  req_body:

module_name = req_body['module']

  

# Try importing the module directly

try:

import_module(module_name)

return  f"Module '{module_name}' already available."

except  ImportError:

pass

  

# Install the module using subprocess

output = install_module(module_name)

  

return  f"Module '{module_name}' installed successfully.\n{output}"

else:

return  "Missing 'module' key in JSON payload."

except  Exception  as  e:

return  f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Azure:**

[image]

[image]

[image]